# automatic title through filter

Tags: filters

the template of my customer looks bad if the user doesn't add an  title at the top of every page.

I want to write a function to add an H1 tag automatially if H1 tags are not present.

**This doesn't work!**

```
    function auto_dummy_titles($content) {
    if (strpos($content,'<h1>') == false) {
        echo '<h1>PLEASE ADD H1 TITLE TO THE PAGE</h1>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'auto_dummy_titles');
```

**It does work just if I write 'h1' instead of ''**
Why?

Comment: `strpos($content,'<h1>') === false` with 3 equal signs

Comment: Why are your "titles" in the post content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why your "titles" are in the post body content, but you should not be `echo`ing content from that filter. You should be creating and returning a string.

```
function auto_dummy_titles($content) {
    if (strpos($content,'<h1>') === false) {
      $content = '<h1>PLEASE ADD H1 TITLE TO THE PAGE</h1>'.$content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'auto_dummy_titles');
```

The function does work though. I can't help but think that the problem is that you should be checking the actual post title for a title and not the post content.

Comment: My "titles" are

Comment: Your titles are what?

Comment: I red about the operators but why did you use === instead of == ? Aren't we sure that we are comparing strings here? Anyway, your hint is totally right and your code too. The titles need to be added into the content since the name of the page will be something that the client will remember (e.g. Homepage) and the slug will be seoed too: both of them won't be included into the H1 tag. Thank you!

Comment: `===` is a strict comparison. It checks the data type as well as the value. `==` will be `false` for `0` and for a strict boolean `false`. `===` will be true only for a strict `false`